# Ribbon: Unable to set default configuration using @RibbonClients(defaultConfiguration=...)

Tags: spring-cloud

The `@RibbonClients` annotation allows us to customise the Ribbon configuration per client. This process is described in the documentation at http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html#_customizing_the_ribbon_client

This is all fine. I tried to use the same approach to override the *default* configuration that should be applied to all my clients. So I defined the following configuration class and made sure it is considered by the component scan:

```
@Configuration
@RibbonClients(defaultConfiguration = MyDefaultRibbonConfig.class)
public class MyRibbonAutoConfiguration {

}
```

Unfortunately, it turns out that `MyDefaultRibbonConfig` is not taken into account when building the ribbon client's application context. A quick look and trace at `RibbonClientConfigurationRegistrar` let me think my `@RibbonClients(default=...)` annotation is unconditionally overridden by the one provided by `org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.eureka.RibbonEurekaAutoConfiguration`.

However, it works if the `@RibbonClients` annotation is set on a **inner class** instead of a top-level class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyRibbonAutoConfiguration {

   @Configuration
   @RibbonClients(defaultConfiguration = MyDefaultRibbonConfig.class)
   static class SubConfig {
   }

}
```

This is a side-effect the strategy followed by `RibbonClientConfigurationRegistrar` to give a name to the discovered configuration beans:

```
        registerClientConfiguration(registry,
                "default." + metadata.getEnclosingClassName(),
                attrs.get("defaultConfiguration"));
```

The configuration for annotations declared on a top-level class are then registered with a bean name set to `default.null.defaultConfiguration` - so the next one overrides the previous (not sure the order is predictable though).

This behaviour looks strange to me. Did I miss something? Should I proceed differently?

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/374 for a follow-up

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in SpringCloud-Netflix 1.0.1. See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/374 for more information.